# MPI_Comm_split explanation

Tags: c++, mpi

Can someone explain and tell me more about MPI_Comm_split communicator?

```
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_row, my_rank,&my_row_comm);
```

This is just example i met by reading some basic documentations. Maybe someone could tell me how this  communicator is working?

Comment: How could we possibly answer this question without the contents of those variables?

Comment: added more info about this

Comment: Please use meaningful question titles.

Comment: The two are just two different variables with different names, I don't understand what you are asking. Different programs use different names for their variables.

Comment: Which aspect of [the documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_split.3.php) do you not understand?

Comment: int color , i dont know what that mean ?  It's says like some splitting integer key, but how it works ?

Answer (score 16):

Just to begin with, let's have a look at the man page:

```
MPI_Comm_split(3)                     MPI                    MPI_Comm_split(3)

NAME
       MPI_Comm_split -  Creates new communicators based on colors and keys

SYNOPSIS
       int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm *newcomm)

INPUT PARAMETERS
       comm   - communicator (handle)
       color  - control of subset assignment (nonnegative integer).  Processes
              with the same color are in the same new communicator
       key    - control of rank assignment (integer)

OUTPUT PARAMETERS
       newcomm
              - new communicator (handle)
```

So what does that do? 
Well, as the name suggests, it will split the communicator `comm` into **disjoint** sub-communicators `newcomm`. Each process of `comm` will be into one unique of these sub-communicators, hence the fact that the output `newcomm` is only one single communicator (for the current process). However, globally speaking, you have to understand that the many versions of `newcomm` are different sub-communicators, partitioning the input `comm`.

So that is what the function does. But how does it do it?
Well, that's where the two parameters `color` and `key` come into play:

- `color` is an integer value that permits to decide in which of the sub-communicators the current process will fall. More specifically, all processes of `comm` for which `color` will have the same numerical value will be part of the same sub-communicator `newcomm`. For example, if you were to define `color = rank%2;` (with `rank` the rank of the process in `comm`), then you would create (globally) two new communicators: one for the processes of odd ranks, and one for the processes of even ranks. However, keep in mind that each processes will only be seeing the one of these new communicators they are part of... So in summary, `color` permits to tell apart the various "teams" you will create, like the colour of the jersey football teams will wear to distinguish themselves during a match (hence the naming I presume).
- `key` will just permit to optionally decide how the processes will be ranked into the new communicators they are part of. For example, if you set `key = rank;`, then the **order** of ranking (not the ranking itself) in each new communicators `newcomm` will follow the order of ranking in the original communicator `comm`. But if you don't care about the ordering, you can as well set `key=0;` and the ranking in each of the new communicators will be whatever the library decides...

Finally, two trivial examples:

- `MPI_Comm_split(comm, 0, rank, &newcomm)` will just duplicate `comm` into `newcomm` (just as `MPI_Comm_dup()`)
- `MPI_Comm_split(comm, rank, rank, &newcomm)` will just return an equivalent of `MPI_COMM_SELF` for each of the processes