# Question on MPI with Fortran: how to broadcast data to shared memory?

Tags: memory, fortran, mpi

I am working on a Fortran code with MPI on ray-tracing.

The issue is that the code has a large array that is needed in all processors.

But this array is read-only for all processors at every time step,
then it is updated at the beginning of the next time step.

The current code uses one processor to read this array from an external file,
then simply broadcast it to all processors. In this way, every processor has a copy of this array.

To save some memory, I was planning to use OpenMP, but this question [MPI Fortran code: how to share data on node via openMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797298/mpi-fortran-code-how-to-share-data-on-node-via-openmp) shows that MPI3.0 can do the trick.

But in the answers of the above question, unfortunately there is no example on how to broadcast the array to nodes.
I wonder anyone can help to provide an example?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I included some more details of the code structure as suggested by Vladimir.

Below is a pseudo-code showing the current treatment in the code:

```
allocate(largearray,size)
do i=1,10
  !!! Update largearray
  if(myrank==0) then
     ~~~read from file~~~ largearray
     call MPI_BCAST(largearray,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     do while(.true.)
       call MPI_RECEIVE(results)
       call collector(results,final_product)
       exit
     end do
     call output(final_product,i)
  else
     call MPI_BCAST(largearray,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
     call radiation(largearray,beams)
     call raytracing(beams,largearray,results)
     call MPI_SEND(results,0)
  end if
end do
deallocate(largearray)
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [help]. We will likely need much more actual code from you. We need to know what data is where and which process needs a direct access to which part and a private part of what. There is currently no visible need for sharing in your insufficient pseudocode.

Comment: Why don’t you simply run one MPI task per node, and let OpenMP use all the available resources ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That's usually the best way, but in a code that already uses MPI and just wants to share a few read only(ish) objects it can be a lost easier to use MPI's shared memory facilities for them and leave the rest of the code more or less unchanged - you don't have !$omp parallelise loads of loops that way.

Comment: Been meaning to write an answer but no time at the moment. Simplest is to use mpi_comm_split_type to create an n node communicator, mpi_comm_split to create a communicator containing only those processes with a rank of zero in the communicators created by mpi_comm_split_type, and the mpi_bcast across that last communicator - being careful to synchronize the non-participating processes.

Comment: The code itself is completely in MPI. In the updated pseudo-code, the radiation and raytracing subroutines are all MPI-involved, so it would be too much work to switch to OpenMP. @IanBush This can be a stupid question, but how to use mpi_comm_split to create the communicator that you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: I do not see much difference in the pseudocode, you added very little.  What data is where? Which data must be shared?  In which parts of your code is it used? Which of the shared data is to be communicated by broadcasting? You are only showing some procedure calls, but MPI and memory sharing is about **data** parallelism and distribution.

Comment: @astrophyszhc A quick google brings up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532233/mpi-comm-split-explanation

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for the info! I think I get that part correct now. One more question, when I broadcast the shared memory, should I broadcast the win handle object, or the Fortran pointer that points to the shared memory? I am not sure whether MPI_win_allocate_shared will allocate an array with contiguous memory or not. Thanks!